# Convert longitude/latitude to x/y on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, math, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I am showing an image in an UIImageView and i'd like to convert coordinates to x/y values so i can show cities on this image.
This is what i tried based on my research:

```
CGFloat height = mapView.frame.size.height;
CGFloat width = mapView.frame.size.width;


 int x =  (int) ((width/360.0) * (180 + 8.242493)); // Mainz lon
 int y =  (int) ((height/180.0) * (90 - 49.993615)); // Mainz lat


NSLog(@"x: %i y: %i", x, y);

PinView *pinView = [[PinView alloc]initPinViewWithPoint:x andY:y];

[self.view addSubview:pinView];
```

which gives me 167 as x and y=104 but this example should have the values x=73 and y=294.

mapView is my UIImageView, just for clarification.

So my second try was to use the MKMapKit:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(49.993615, 8.242493);
MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord);
NSLog(@"x is %f and y is %f",point.x,point.y);
```

But this gives me some really strange values: 
x = 140363776.241755 and y is 91045888.536491.

So do you have an idea what i have to do to get this working ?

Thanks so much!

Comment: By what formula you want to find x and y?

Comment: by a formula that works :D i just searched through the internet and found the formula above. Basically i have my iPhone Screen which shows a image of a country and i want to find citys on this image via longitude and latitude coordinates.

Comment: the formula above is for mecator projection. And i thought i have something like that. Here is a Screenshot of my project: http://cl.ly/LySY. The little black dot should pointing at the city "Mainz" (in the middle-left). And not to the upper-middle in the near of "Bremen"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make this work you need to know 4 pieces of data:

1. Latitude and longitude of the top left corner of the image.
2. Latitude and longitude of the bottom right corner of the image.
3. Width and height of the image (in points).
4. Latitude and longitude of the data point.

With that info you can do the following:

```
// These should roughly box Germany - use the actual values appropriate to your image
double minLat = 54.8;
double minLong = 5.5;
double maxLat = 47.2;
double maxLong = 15.1;

// Map image size (in points)
CGSize mapSize = mapView.frame.size;

// Determine the map scale (points per degree)
double xScale = mapSize.width / (maxLong - minLong);
double yScale = mapSize.height / (maxLat - minLat);

// Latitude and longitude of city
double spotLat = 49.993615;
double spotLong = 8.242493;

// position of map image for point
CGFloat x = (spotLong - minLong) * xScale;
CGFloat y = (spotLat - minLat) * yScale;
```

If `x` or `y` are negative or greater than the image's size, then the point is off of the map.

This simple solution assumes the map image uses the basic cylindrical projection (Mercator) where all lines of latitude and longitude are straight lines.

Edit:

To convert an image point back to a coordinate, just reverse the calculation:

```
double pointLong = pointX / xScale + minLong;
double pointLat = pointY / yScale + minLat;
```

where `pointX` and `pointY` represent a point on the image in screen points. (0, 0) is the top left corner of the image.

Comment: First of all thanks ! But i tried this code and i get x:-115.473389 y:-230.305954. But the point (49.993615, 8.242493) should'nt be off the map. So how can the values be negative and how can i calculate the right values ?!

Comment: Sorry, I had the `xScale` and `yScale` partially backwards. See my updates for those two lines.

Comment: is there also the possibility to convert it back to longitude & latitude from x/y pixels ? Because i want to get the distance between 2 coordinates on my image-map.

Comment: ok great thanks. I testes this with a lot of citys and it turns out that the x value is slighty different everytime. Is there anything you missed ? Or is it just because my max and minLong are not exact enough ?

Comment: @DavidEhlen Your x and y values will be off if your min and max values are not exact enough or if the image is not actually a true Mercator projection.