# convert Lat/Long to X,Y Coordinates in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, geolocation, coordinates

i have to calculate the X,Y Points on the given image from the lat long data.

i have one custom image used as map and i have some predifned data of X,Y co ordinate of one point with its related geolocation data(Lat,Long)

e.g for at one specific point in image my `x=20,y=20` and for this point i have predefined value of geolocation data is`(23.0000,72.00000)`

so when i want to show geolocation data of `23.0000 ,72.0000` then i will directly refer to `x=20,y=20`.

now if i want to calculate X,Y co ordinate value if i have some another geolocation data than how can i get those value of x y on my image on basis of that one predefined points?

Comment: if all you know is one point, you won't make it.

Comment: not even if i know the only lat,long?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185584/convert-longitude-latitude-to-x-y-on-iphone

Comment: if you only got one point on a two dimensional structure this is just to enough. You can't describe a surface with just one point. therefor there is also no converting. No matter in what unit you have that point.

Comment: By 'custom map image' do you mean a customised version of MKMapView or just an image/picture of a map? If its a picture please edit your question to use 'custom coordinate system' instead of lat long and don't use the word 'map'. Because in iOS by 'map' we generally mean MapKit and  your question will get answers or get closed as duplicate referring to MapKit framework.